# Как устроены трансляторы ассемблера?

Tags: python-3.x, ассемблер, компилятор

Знаю, что трансляторы языков высокого уровня делятся на несколько этапов (лексер, синтаксический анализ и т.д.).

А что насчет ассемблера? Он довольно простой, а значит и все эти этапы в виде отдельных подпрограмм не нужны (кроме лексера)? Условный пример транслятора ассемблера условного компьютера (учитывая, что в tokens содержатся все токены текущей строки):

```
command = tokens[0]

if command == "ADD":
    # у команды ADD 2 аргумента, а значит в сумме ровно 3 токена
    if len(tokens) != 3:
        error()

    first_arg = tokens[1]
    second_arg = tokens[2]

    # проверяем, является ли first_arg регистром
    # проверяем, является ли second_arg регистром или числом

    # а дальше формируем машинный код, т.е. формируем n-битную инструкцию,
    # так же проходясь по токенам
```

Будет ли такая организация транслятора достаточно гибкой, удобочитаемой и вообще правильной?

Comment: В нормальном ассемблере есть куча директив управления памятью и еще есть макросы так что это вполне себе полноценный транслятор.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, пишу транслятор простого ассемблера (для LC-3, если знаете), без этих всех примочек. Способ в вопросе подойдет для такого?

Comment: Если просто потренироваться, то сойдет что угодно. Если потом пользоваться, то понадобится все, что есть в нормальных ассемблерах.

Comment: Если у вас несколько десятков команд, то таким образом описывать каждую команду не очень удобно. Лучше разбить на группы (без операндов, 1 операнд, 2 операнда), в каждой группе уже разбить на подгруппы по способу генерации машинного кода, по типам операндов и т.д.